# How to change 6.2 Documents and Media Display view like 6.0.6

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have installed Liferay 6.2 in my personal site. But i need Documents and Media Display view same as Liferay 6.0.6 not like 6.2 format ,Because when i click Liferay 6.2 documents at Documents and Media Display it is drive to another details page, i need to download documents when i click documents (same as 6.0.6)

If any one have HOOKs for Documents and Media Display and how to change "rowHREF" line please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider to look into "ADT" (Application Display Templates). Some of Liferay's Portlets accept Freemarker templates for the display. For example Media Gallery does, and comes with an example in the global scope. Check if Document and Media Display has the same (or just use Media Gallery).